# Casting a spell and a bonus action spell then using a reaction

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, reactions

I have an interesting edge condition.

If I cast [Healing Word](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/healing-word) as a Bonus Action and [Fire Bolt](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fire-bolt) as an Action, can I still cast [Shield](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shield) as a reaction?